# getting all values from a concurrent dictionary and clearing it without losing data

Tags: c#, .net

I am adding/updating objects into a concurrent dictionary and periodically (every minute) flushing the dictionary, so my code looks something like this:

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Metric> _metrics = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Metric>();

    public static void IncrementCountMetricBy(string name, int count)
    {           
        _metrics.AddOrUpdate(....
    }

    public static Metric[] Flush()
    {
        var flushedMetrics = _metrics;
        _metrics = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Metric>();
        return flushedMetrics.Values.ToArray();
    }
```

now I'm not sure if it's possible for this code to lose some objects/updates

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a `ConcurrentDictionary`, thanks :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you could *potentially* lose some data there:

1. The incrementing thread could *read* the `_metrics` field and get the old dictionary, and then be interrupted
2. The flushing thread then replaces the `_metrics` field with the new dictionary
3. The flushing thread than called `Values.ToArray()`
4. The incrementing thread then calls `AddOrUpdate` on a dictionary which is no longer being looked at by anything. (The one that it fetched in step 1.)

To put it another way, imagine that your `IncrementMetricCountBy` method is actually:

```
public static void IncrementCountMetricBy(string name, int count)
{
    var tmp = _metrics;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);           
    tmp.AddOrUpdate(...);
}
```

If you can see why that isn't safe, the same argument applies in your current code.

As far as I can see there isn't anything particularly simple that you can do with `ConcurrentDictionary` here. One option would be to take a snapshot of all the keys, and then remove them all:

```
var keys = _metrics.Keys.ToList();
var values = new List<Metric>();
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    Metric metric;
    if (_metrics.TryRemove(key, out metric))
    {
        values.Add(metric);
    }
}
return values;
```

The dictionary may not be *empty* when you return, but you shouldn't lose any data. (You may get metrics updated since the method started, and any update which happens after a key has been removed will end up re-adding it, but that should be okay.)

Comment: What if `TryRemove` fails?

Comment: @Romoku: Then the value won't be added to the list. I could only see that happening if something else removed an item from the dictionary though - e.g. if `Flush` is called from two threads concurrently. (I'm assuming nothing *else* removes entries.)

Comment: @Romoku It would mean a key was removed after the start of the method.  Are there any other threads removing values from the dictionary?  If not, that shouldn't ever happen.

Comment: @JonSkeet Instead of removing values one by one, wouldn't it be possible to use [`Interlocked.Exchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=net-6.0)?


`var newMetrics = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Metric>();
var flushedMetrics = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _metrics, newMetrics);`

Comment: @Katebrich: Potentially, yes. It sort of depends on what else might be using the dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

It is.  Consider the follow case:

1. Thread one calls `AddOrUpdate`, but stop execution immediately after the start of the call, before *any* actions (including taking out any locks) are taken in that method.
2. Thread two copies all of the values of the dictionary.
3. Thread one goes back to finish adding the item.

That item would then be lost.

Comment: If the incrementing thread is interrupted before *any* actions are taken, it's okay - it's only a problem if the `_metrics` field is read, but `AddOrUpdate` isn't called before the interrupt

Comment: @JonSkeet How would the case I described end up okay?  It sounds to me like you described the start of the window of opportunity for "bad things" to happen and I described the end of that window.

Comment: I misread your call to AddOrUpdate as a call to IncrementCountMetricBy. Sorry!